How to volunteer as a temporary research assistant?
I'm in a role in industry with a 9 month paid period governed by a non-compete clause. If I were to leave this job, I'd like to do something productive during the non-compete period, before starting my next job. Does anyone have any experience of having unpaid temporary researchers / assistants in academia? How did these temporary researchers get the role? Should I think about trying to forge these connections now with academics whose research I find interesting? How would you recommend trying to make these connections?
For additional context, I have a master's degree (so some, but pretty limited experience of academic research) and my job is writing mathematical/statistical software (presumably a useful skill for certain areas).

What country are you interested in?

@buffy I'm based in the UK but it wouldn't necessarily have to be here (though I don't know how visas etc. would work elsewhere)

Is your goal to do something useful and productive in the short term or to try to move towards academia in the long term?

what is your goal? if you want to study PhD then doing this for potential advisor will be a good way.

There are a fair number of mathematical software projects needing some serious project management as well as documentation (because mathematicians as a group tend to have less of those skills, and less inclination to do those tasks).  Are you interested (and capable) in those kinds of tasks?

@BryanKrause, the former. I like my job and I'm not considering this with the intention of changing career (though I guess I'm open to it if it turns out I really love it). I'm just looking to do something useful and interesting for a short period.

In some places there might be laws that govern what you can do as an "unpaid employee". But I doubt that anywhere you would be prevented from a collegial and collaborative relationship with an academic that didn't involve pay.
The problem would be contacting people who might value your skills and wish to collaborate. It is too easy to ignore blind emails. But there are a lot of folks who could benefit from having a skilled model builder on the team.
The best place (in some fields) to meet people is at conferences where the coffee table is a good place to start conversations. You can also stay after talks and discuss what you can offer.
The second best place, I think, is to go to a local university and ask for the possibility of meeting people. You might need to go through "official" channels to get started, say by visiting a department head. There is usually a coffee lounge in large departments where informal conversations happen.
The third (perhaps) idea is to have a former professor make contact on your behalf with a few people who might have a need for your skills.
In all of these, the big obstacle is getting ignored on first contact attempts. People have no reason to trust you initially.
You might get a co-authorship eventually if you can make that contact, but you might also need to promise some participation after your 9-month period ends.
And, the things you seem to be contemplating don't necessarily require co-location. There are a lot of tools for remote collaboration these days.

I am a professor of mathematics and statistics. You wrote:

my job is writing mathematical/statistical software (presumably a useful skill for certain areas).

Yes, that's an extremely useful skill-set! If such a person lived in my city, I'd be happy to collaborate (working together over zoom would also work, but then I'd need to be more confident that the other person really knew what they were doing). I'm constantly given far too many interesting research questions (many by colleagues in other departments who want help with a more statistical or computational approach to a research question in their field), and could use help on them, which could lead to a joint publication. I suspect that there are plenty of professors who would be happy for such help.
Another option you should consider is to do a self-directed project and put it on your GitHub. You want a portfolio of projects to show when you apply for jobs. Even my professor friends who are trying to leave academia end up spending months doing such projects to show their chops in the kinds of settings that future employers will value.
Lastly, you can use your skillset and free time to contribute to open source software projects. I have been told by folks who moved from academia to industry that this kind of contribution is valued, and that it would also earn you respect from others who contribute to such projects. A lot of people who contribute are outside academia, so their respect can matter a lot when you're looking for a job.
As for your other questions:

Does anyone have any experience of having unpaid temporary researchers / assistants?

I've had plenty of students do research with me that has led to publications or to them updating their github with a new project completed. I'd view your situation as analogous but you probably have far stronger programming skills and maturity than most of the students who work with me.

How did these temp researchers get the role?

The students ask me. When my colleagues elsewhere want me to work with their students on a project, the colleague sends me an email outlining the project and trying to get me interested. When a random member of the community wants to work together, they also "pitch" an idea to me by email. But it helps if I already know the person or if there's an introduction by someone I do know, because professors do get a lot of random emails from people wanting to work together, and don't necessarily delve deeply into all cases.

Should I think about trying to forge these connections now with academics whose research I find interesting? How would you recommend trying to make these connections?

Yes, absolutely. Line it up ahead of time. Professors are very busy and need to know a new person will be coming on board, to block out regular times for meetings. Email is the way to go, and leveraging your network (former professors of yours for example). You can find professors you might want to work with by searching for recent research, e.g., on Google scholar, doing the kind of stuff that you feel you're good at.
